# Selenium regression testing on page templates which may or may not be switched on

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, serenity-bdd

Our dev team are working on new page templates which include lots of changes to the locators on those pages. These new pages are on a toggle so they may or may not be present at any time in our test environments depending on whether they are toggled on or off.
An id is in the header which I can use to identify if the new page template is toggled on.
Can anyone tell me the best way to handle this. Ideally I would like to add the new locators to the relevant page object and not put them in a properties file.

Current locator and WebElement:

```
@FindBy(className = "add-to-cart-btn")
    WebElementFacade addToCartBtn;
```

New locator on new template:

```
className = "quickOrderSubmit"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Is this toggling done for the whole site at the same time? Or some pages can have old locators and others new ones at the same time?

Comment: @Grasshopper the toggling is done at page level.

Comment: @charliebigpotato There is a way of using an ternary expression in the findby annotation - Flag.devEnv ? NewLocators : OldLocators. The problem is that the flag.devenv needs to be compile time constants and thus cannot be deduced from the header. This is easy to implement for the site as a whole or maybe few pages. BTW how are you accessing this header?

Comment: @Grasshopper sorry my mistake, its an id in the body not the header.

Comment: Do both locators exist when a page is toggled on? e.g. If the page is toggled on, do both elements exist but only one is visible, etc.?

Comment: @JeffC No only the new loctators will exist if the new page is toggled on, and the old ones will exist when toggled off.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to keep the old and new locators in the same place by using a custom `ElementLocatorFactory, ElementLocator and Annotations` class. These will fit in easily into the page object model. It makes use of the combination of `using` and `locator value (id,class,css,xpath etc)` fields of the FindBy annotation. This is a hack of the usage of FindBy. A new annotation would be better but that is too much work.

This will be integrated into the PageFactory initElements method by using the below code in the constructor of the pageobject class.

```
OldNewElementLocatorFactory onelf = new OldNewElementLocatorFactory(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(onelf, this);
```

---

Usage -

- **Same locator strategy for old and new.** For example id have changed.

**@FindBy(using="id@@id", id="newid@@oldid")** or @FindBy(using="name@@name", name="newname@@oldname")

**using part** - The first part before the delimiter is the locator strategy for **new** locator and the second part is for the **old** locator.

**id part** - The first part is the value for the **new** locator strategy and the second for the **old**.

- **Different locator strategy for old and new.** For example id has now changed to name.

**@FindBy(using="name@@id", name="newname", id="oldid")** or @FindBy(using="xpath@@css", xpath="//div/input[@id='comboid2']", css="div input[id='comboid2']")

**using part** - Same as above.

**name part** - Locator value for new name strategy.

**id part** - Locator value for old id strategy.

- **The same applies for FindBy used along with the List type variable**

@FindBy(using="class@@tag", className="newClass", tagName="input")
private List inputs;

@FindBy(using="class@@class", className="newClass@@oldClass")
private List sameInputs;

- **Allows the standard format of use of FindBy annotation. No changes required.**
  @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="origid") or  @FindBy(id="origid")

`ElementLocatorFactory` - The fields `isNew and oldNewChecked` manages the issue whether the new or old locators are used. These are in this class as the locators can vary at page level. If you are not using Java8 then you will need to modify `verifyPageAge()` method. Take care to make sure that the search for the old new locator switch is performed only once.

```
public class OldNewElementLocatorFactory implements ElementLocatorFactory {

    private final SearchContext searchContext;

    private boolean isNew = false;
    private boolean oldNewCecked = false;

    public OldNewElementLocatorFactory(SearchContext searchContext) {
        this.searchContext = searchContext;
    }

    public ElementLocator createLocator(Field field) {
        OldNewElementLocator elemLoc = new OldNewElementLocator(searchContext, field);
        elemLoc.setFactory(this);
        return elemLoc;
    }

    public void verifyPageAge(Supplier<Boolean> newLoc) {
        if (!oldNewCecked) {
            oldNewCecked=true;
            if (newLoc.get())
                isNew=true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    public void setNew(boolean isNew) {
        this.isNew = isNew;
    }

    public boolean isOldNewCecked() {
        return oldNewCecked;
    }

    public void setOldNewCecked(boolean oldNewCecked) {
        this.oldNewCecked = oldNewCecked;
    }
}
```

`ElementLocator` - This handles the searching of new old locator switch in method `verifyNewLocators()`. You will need to modify this method to search for your flag. I assumed any element with the  id of newloc. If not on Java8 then you will need to modify method `createOldNewBy()`.

```
public class OldNewElementLocator implements ElementLocator {

    private final SearchContext searchContext;
    private final boolean shouldCache;
    private By by = null;
    private WebElement cachedElement;
    private List<WebElement> cachedElementList;
    private OldNewAnnotations annotations;


    private OldNewElementLocatorFactory factory;

    public OldNewElementLocator(SearchContext searchContext, Field field) {
        this(searchContext, new OldNewAnnotations(field));
    }

    public OldNewElementLocator(SearchContext searchContext, OldNewAnnotations annotations) {
        this.searchContext = searchContext;
        this.shouldCache = annotations.isLookupCached();
        this.annotations = annotations;

        this.by = annotations.buildBy();
    }

    public OldNewElementLocatorFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public void setFactory(OldNewElementLocatorFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    protected boolean verifyNewLocators() {
        return (searchContext.findElements(By.id("newloc")).size() == 1) ? true : false;
    }

    protected void createOldNewBy() {
        factory.verifyPageAge(this::verifyNewLocators);
        if(by==null) {
            by = annotations.buildOldNewBy(factory.isNew());
        }
        System.out.println(by.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    public WebElement findElement() {
        if (cachedElement != null && shouldCache) {
            return cachedElement;
        }

        createOldNewBy();

        WebElement element = searchContext.findElement(by);
        if (shouldCache) {
            cachedElement = element;
        }

        return element;
    }

    public List<WebElement> findElements() {
        if (cachedElementList != null && shouldCache) {
            return cachedElementList;
        }

        createOldNewBy();

        List<WebElement> elements = searchContext.findElements(by);
        if (shouldCache) {
            cachedElementList = elements;
        }

        return elements;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " '" + by + "'";
    }
}
```

`Annotations` - This manages the parsing logic for creating the By objects. Also contains the hard coded delimiter i have used - @@. Change it or create a static field for this.

```
public class OldNewAnnotations extends Annotations {

    public OldNewAnnotations(Field field) {
        super(field);
    }

    public By buildBy() {
        if (assertNewOldFind())
            return null;
        return super.buildBy();
    }

    public By buildOldNewBy(boolean isNew) {

        if (!assertNewOldFind())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "If you set the 'using' property, you cannot also set 'how'");

        FindBy findBy = getField().getAnnotation(FindBy.class);

        String[] using = findBy.using().split("@@");
        String strategy = isNew ? using[0] : using[1];

        switch (strategy) {

        case "id":
            return By.id(getStrategyLocator(findBy.id(), isNew));

        case "name":
            return By.name(getStrategyLocator(findBy.name(), isNew));

        case "class":
            return By.className(getStrategyLocator(findBy.className(), isNew));

        case "css":
            return By.cssSelector(getStrategyLocator(findBy.css(), isNew));

        case "xpath":
            return By.xpath(getStrategyLocator(findBy.xpath(), isNew));

        case "link":
            return By.linkText(getStrategyLocator(findBy.linkText(), isNew));

        case "partiallink":
            return By.partialLinkText(getStrategyLocator(
                    findBy.partialLinkText(), isNew));

        case "tag":
            return By.tagName(getStrategyLocator(findBy.tagName(), isNew));
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getStrategyLocator(String value, boolean isNew) {

        if (value.contains("@@")) {
            String[] val = value.split("@@");
            return isNew ? val[0] : val[1];
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected boolean assertNewOldFind() {

        FindBys findBys = getField().getAnnotation(FindBys.class);
        if (findBys != null) return false;

        FindAll findAll = getField().getAnnotation(FindAll.class);
        if (findAll != null) return false;

        FindBy findBy = getField().getAnnotation(FindBy.class);

        if (findBy.how() == How.UNSET && !"".equals(findBy.using()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Cons -

1. Error checking for the new format of annotation usage is not much. You can look at making it robust.
2. It does not handle FindBys and FindAll annotation with the old and new locator together. It could have been easy but Selenium source has some private methods which make it hard to use overriding by inheritance. You can look at having a different way to solve it. Though hardly ever see these annotations used.